# AWS EC2ConfigService (running as System account) does not have local admin rights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

As part of **DevOps** automation computer joins domain at first boot.

I pass Power Shell script as **User Data** when invoking instance creation. Power Shell script invokes executable which `decrypts` domain credentials, renames computer and joins domain.

Executable (which is invoked from PS) fails with error 1323 "Wrong password".

If I logon to instance as local admin and launch same script from `C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Scripts\UserScript.ps1` it works.

Local system account does not have local administrator rights??? I tried to execute script from scheduled task which runs as System account and it failed with same error (1323).

Most interesting, it used to work half a year back.

Is there any EC2 change which would cause this behavior?